# Using Rspec to test for notice after page redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Trying to test for a notice after a page redirect after signed in users try to access the new and create actions.

Spec Failures:

Failures:

```
1) Authentication authorization as signed in master submitting a GET request to the Masters#new action 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_content("You cannot complete this request when signed in.") }
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find xpath "/html"
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:126:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authentication authorization as signed in master submitting a POST request to the Masters#create action 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_content("You cannot complete this request when signed in.") }
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find xpath "/html"
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:132:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Before filter:

```
before_action :already_signed_in, only: [:new, :create]

def already_signed_in
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "You cannot complete this request when signed in." if signed_in?
end
```

authorization specs:

```
context "as signed in master" do 
  let(:master) { FactoryGirl.create(:master) }
  before { sign_in master, no_capybara: true }
  subject { page }

  context "submitting a GET request to the Masters#new action" do 
    before { get new_master_path }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
    it { should have_content("You cannot complete this request when signed in.") }
  end

  context "submitting a POST request to the Masters#create action" do 
    before { post masters_path }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
    it { should have_content("You cannot complete this request when signed in.") }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yeah! The response does not have any content because it is a redirect!

So you can ask the `flash` object if it has a message.

If you really want to know if that is displayed on the next page you would need to write integration tests, because it would actually follow the redirect in the browser and check the subsequent page for the message.

Comment: alright thanks! I made flash[:notice] the subject and then wrote it { should =~ /You cannot complete this request when signed in/i }